# What does the vedas say about diet & what & how to eat?

Tags: vedas

A friend mentioned that guy who is a "Vedic Scholar" he met on a train told him that as per "our scriptures" we are only suppose to consume 1 types of oil. The preferred is just Ghee. If you just follow that one point, you will be healthy.

I want to know:

- Is that correct? Where or in which scripture does it say that?
- Is there any online versions of Vedas that I can read more about it?

FYI: I am totally new to all vedic related matters. I just born to a Hindu parents, but dont know anything about Hinduism. I just starting to learn. Figured I shall start with food, as I am a foodie.

Comment: Ghee is called **ghṛtam** in Sanskrit.  You can read Veda online at the following link (https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/index.htm)

Comment: sesame/gingelly oil is the recommended one. peanut oil is next in line. other modern ones - soybean, sunflower etc. are newer inventions, hence either to be avoided or ignored if possible.

Comment: "Figured I shall start with food, as I am a foodie." - avoid meat, alcohol, onion/garlic, mushroom/drumstick - and you'll start seeing your mental clarity increase within 2 months.

Comment: @ram Why drumstick? That is new.

Comment: @OkBeat9, it falls under leeks which incite sensual instincts.